# Using regex (python) to detext text within (and) brackets

Tags: python, regex

```
strs = [
    "I like to run head first into a wall (not)"
    "klsjlsk klsjdkls ,m s,mdn,mnsd,m (123)"
    "a b c d e f g h i (j?)"
]
```

I want to remove the " (not),  (123),  (j?)"

why is

```
re.sub(r' (\([*]\))$', '', strs(0))
```

not doing it and what's the proper way?

Comment: For easy regex expression testing check: https://regexr.com/

Comment: should be ```re.sub(r'((\.+)\)$', '', strs[0])``` by the way, you have (0) in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```py
import re


strs = [
    "I like to run head first into a wall (not)",
    "klsjlsk klsjdkls ,m s,mdn,mnsd,m (123)",
    "a b c d e f g h i (j?)"
]

# space(\s)
# openbracket(\()
# anychar(.*)
# smallestpossiblematch(?)
# closebracket(\))
pattern = r'\s*\(.*?\)'

# list comprehension with new strings
new = [re.sub(pattern, '', strs[i]) for i in range(len(strs))]
```

Comment: Good to have added `\s`. You may make it optional or multiple with `\s*`

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, I'll edit, thnx @Toto

Answer (score 1):

You're using a capture group (the outside parentheses) to capture everything inside the parentheses. However, since you're not reusing that captured data, that's unnecessary. If you just want to remove all parentheses and the enclosed text at the end of a line (my guess based on what you supplied), you can do

```
re.sub(r'\([^\)]*\)$', '', strs[0])
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/FOTTfi/1

If it's important to remove the space before the parentheses as well, just use a `\s` or `\s+` at the start.

Yours doesn't work because `[*]` isn't doing what you think. It's looking for the literal `*`. If you want to find any number of characters, use `.*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you need to use `print re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', strs[0])`

Comment: can you break that down for me, I have trouble understanding what's happening there.

Comment: @runningmanjoe It checks for a bracket  ```\(``` followed by anything that is not a bracket ```[^)]``` repeated 0 or more time ```*``` then followed by a bracket ```\)```